# encode_contents vs encode("utf-8") in Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, encode

OK, so as a beginner webscraper I feel as though I've seen both used, seemingly interchangeably when converting the default unicode of text in HTML. I know contents() is a list object but other than that, what the heck is the difference?

I've noticed that .encode("utf-8") seems to work more universally.

thanks,

-confused souper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of `encode_contents`:

```
encode_contents(self, indent_level=None, encoding='utf-8', formatter='minimal') method of bs4.BeautifulSoup instance
    Renders the contents of this tag as a bytestring.
```

The documentation of`encode` method:

```
encode(self, encoding='utf-8', indent_level=None, formatter='minimal', errors='xmlcharrefreplace')
```

`encode` method will work on a `bs4.BeautifulSoup` object instance. `encode_contents` will work on the contents of a `bs4.BeautifulSoup` instance.

```
>>> html = "<div>div content <p> a paragraph </p></div>"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.div.encode()
>>> '<div>div content <p> a paragraph </p></div>'
>>> soup.div.contents
>>> [u'div content ', <p> a paragraph </p>]
>>> soup.div.encode_contents()
>>> 'div content <p> a paragraph </p>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The method signature for `encode_contents()` shows that in addition to encoding content, it can also format the output:

```
encode_contents(self, indent_level=None, encoding='utf-8', formatter='minimal') method of bs4.BeautifulSoup instance
    Renders the contents of this tag as a bytestring.
```

For example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><body><p>Caf\xe9</p></body></html>')
>>> soup.encode_contents()
'<html><body><p>Caf\xc3\xa9</p></body></html>'
>>> soup.encode_contents(indent_level=1)
'<html>\n <body>\n  <p>\n   Caf\xc3\xa9\n  </p>\n </body>\n</html>'
>>> soup.encode_contents(indent_level=1, encoding='iso-8859-1')
'<html>\n <body>\n  <p>\n   Caf\xe9\n  </p>\n </body>\n</html>'
```

`str.encode('utf-8')` can only perform the encoding part, no formatting.

Comment: hm. so an .encode_contents() with no parameters specified is the same as .encode('utf-8')?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce: Yes.

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce: Actually, I'm wrong. I thought that you were referring to `str.encode()`, not `soup.encode()`.